# How to blacklist some cell base station on Android 9

Tags: networking

As far as I know, one of approaches for disabling of mobile data traffic during public protests is use a  fake cell base station with strong signal at local area.

I did some research, but I did not find any ways to blacklist some base stations, only tools to monitor them (like Network Cell Info, etc).

Is it any way to block some base station with some tool/programmatically with Android API?

Comment: Fake cell towers aka., IMSI catchers are AFAIK only possible for 2G/3G (as long as the mobile network provider does not cooperate). Therefore if you disable 2G and 3G in your phone and only use 4G/LTE and 5G you should be safe.

Comment: @robert interesting comment. I've googled a bit, and it appears this does help, but it is not a panacea as some attacks can at least partially thwart it.

Comment: thanks, we have no any 5G, will try with LTE